# Creating multi-digit random number on Asterisk server

Tags: random, asterisk

I have a very basic asterisk server that grabs caller ID, and a number from the caller.  I am trying to have it also generate a simple 5 digit number to read back to the caller before hanging up.  I was trying to use RAND but that will only give me 1 digit.  I've tried everything I can think of and find on the net.

Any thoughts on how to get this function to work?  I just need to create a "random" 5 digit number while everything else is running.

Thanks for any help on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rand(10000,99999) should give you the 5 digit number

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I should have figured that out... lol...  Always the easy ones... :)